why does my Kivy app crashes on startup on android
SI developed an app forandroid using the kivy framework, the resulted APK from the kivy buildozer keeps crashing when installed on the android phone.
I'm using Huwai Y9s
here are the logcat error messages when running the app in the android studio emulator
 E  LoadAppImageStartupCache enabled : 1
 E  Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
 E  Fail to acquire dataAnalyzerService...
 E  AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@d4057bc
 E  AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@688d345
 E  Invalid ID 0x00000000.
 E  notifyActivityState pkg:org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity state:2 fg:true mUid:10458
 E  [SurfaceView - org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity#0] No local sync point found
 E  win=Window{fdd8db3 u0 Splash Screen org.test.myapp EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true
 E  channel '67b60f6 org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
 E  notifyActivityState pkg:org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity state:20 fg:false mUid:10458



here are my main.py file
import requests
import pprint
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import MDListItem, MDListItemHeadlineText
#from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion, AccordionItem
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFabButton

# Designate Our .kv design file 
Builder.load_file('box.kv')


global data_price_unique
global data
data = []
data_price_unique = []


######### Get the api response ############
def first_tier(item_name):  ## get a list of items with unique products 
    global data
    global data_price_unique
    parameters = {
        "ItemName": item_name
    }
    response = requests.get("https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyMst1biNF1MXOZCkEhAS7cbmVM4qEwhQbziT7oPVmXZgZ_FGzRYDgenCNpAP2ovWU7/exec", params=parameters)
    response.raise_for_status()
    data = response.json()['data']
    #pprint.pprint(response.json()['data'])
    data_price_unique = list({item["Price"]:item for item in data}.values())
    #pprint.pprint(data_price_unique    )
    return data_price_unique


def second_tier(item_name, price):
        discount_data = [ d for d in data if d['Price'] == price]
        #pprint.pprint(discount_data)
        MyLayout().add_item_2(item_name=item_name ,discount_data=discount_data)
        #print(item_name)


####### data populated from json response
class Listitem(MDListItem): # create list items
    
    def item_press(self):
        #global item_name
        #global price
        item_name =  self.ids.label1.text
        if "%" not in item_name: # check if there are items in accordion 1
            #print(item_name)
            price = item_name.rsplit(':', 1)[-1]
            #print(price)
            #print(item_name)
            second_tier(item_name, price)
            #return item_name
        else:
            pass        
    
######### main Layout ################
class MyLayout(Widget):

    
    def add_item(self):
        global data_price_unique

        self.ids.container_1.clear_widgets() #clear items in accordion 2


        self.ids.title1.title = self.ids.name.text  # change accordion 2 title
        self.ids.title1.collapse = False   # expand the accordion 2 
        self.ids.label2.text = "Searching"

        item_name = self.ids.name.text
        first_tier(item_name=item_name)

        if len(data_price_unique) == 0: #### if there is no product 
            self.ids.label2.text = "No product found"
        else:
            for n in range(len(data_price_unique)):   # loop to extract data 
                item = Listitem()
                self.ids.container_1.add_widget(item)
                #print(data_price_unique[n]['ItemName'])
                item.ids.label1.text = f"product name: {data_price_unique[n]['ItemName']}            \
                                price:{data_price_unique[n]['Price'] }"
                n += 1
        
        #self.ids.title1.collapse = False   # expand the accordion 2 

    def add_item_2(self, item_name, discount_data):  ## populate Accordion 1
        app = App.get_running_app()
        # for n in range(len(data_price_unique)):   
        #   self.remove_widget(item)
        app.root.ids.container_2.clear_widgets() #clear items in accordion 1
        
        for n in range(len(discount_data)):
            item = Listitem()
            app.root.ids.container_2.add_widget(item) 
            item.ids.label1.text = f"product name: {discount_data[n]['ItemName']}   \
             Store: {discount_data[n]['Store']}   \
             Discount:   {discount_data[n]['Discount'] } %"
            n += 1 

        app.root.ids.title_product.title = item_name
        app.root.ids.title_product.collapse = False ## expand accordion 1
        
        #print(item_name)
        #print(self.ids.title_product)
        #print(AccordionItem.ids.<kivy.uix.accordion.AccordionItem)


class MaestroApp(MDApp):
    dialog = None
    
    def build(self):
        #Clock.schedule_once(self.add_item_2)
        return MyLayout()
        

    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MaestroApp().run()

and here are my kv file content
<Listitem>
    
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 30
    on_press: root.item_press()
    MDListItemHeadlineText:
        id: label1
        text: "item name{}                              Headline  5555"


<MyLayout>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "Maestro"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            font_size: 55

        Accordion:
            orientation: 'vertical' 
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 600

            AccordionItem:
                id:title_product
                title: "Panel 1"
                ScrollView:
                    MDList:
                        id: container_2  
        
            AccordionItem:
                id:title1
                title: "Panel 2"
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    Label:
                        id: label2
                        text: "Maestro"
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: 50
                        font_size: 55
                    ScrollView:
                        MDList:
                            id: container_1    

            AccordionItem:
                title: "Panel 3"
                Label:
                    text: "Panel 3 text"
                    font_size: 20


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height

            Label:
                text: "Name"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 50
                size_hint_x: None
                width:100

            TextInput:
                id: name
                multiline:False
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 50     
        

        Button:
            text: "Submit"
            font_size: 32
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            on_press: root.add_item()        


as the app is running smoothly on windows, I'm not sure what is causing its crash on the android.
could anyone suggest what is causing such problem
I build the apk using the following google colab
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_4KVC-BA3hoQc-m8Zi2jNL8Huak1n9Vd#scrollTo=uu1FE_N4GWc_
